# StackOverflow user leagues reputation doesn't match

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

While I was perusing [this list](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) today, I noticed that it stated my all-time rep was 412 when it actually is 453 (as of now).

Does this reputation take time to update itself? (I had gotten a few upvotes *just* before I checked). I'm just curious.

Comment: *Does this reputation take time to update itself?* **Yes. Exactly.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leagues capture reputation standings at UTC 00:00 every day, they do not update in real time.

Comment: Much obliged :)

Comment: Sounds right, you have link to something official?